# Prgressive House sound of bjornberg

Tags: sound-design

i want to make the sound at 2:14 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-knHOaAeFA

what i've got so far: http://www48.zippyshare.com/v/86291041/file.html

What i'm doing wrong?

please help

Answer (score 2):

Your clip is actually remarkably close in sound, so you're off to a very good start. What I hear in the original is a significantly higher level of compression, as well as "ducking" from the kick drum. If nothing else this will help you match the perceived level of your track with the original.

As for your lead synth, I'm fairly certain that you are missing a couple of supporting counter-melodies. Listen really closely as there is harmonic material beyond the melody that you put in your track. I'm not sure what specific parameters you have available on your lead synth, but you might also try increasing the number of oscillator voices that are playing the lead line, and boost up the **UNISON** parameter (i.e., random pitch variation) of each oscillator. You can also do this by assigning a fast, random LFO to both the pitch and the pan of the oscillators.

Best,
~Matt

Comment: Great response!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you meant to ask this question in one of the communities of the "the other" sound design. The one that's mainly about programming synth sounds, although all the stuff is related of course... :)